# Separate width and height from data-src using .split() not working (Undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve the width and height of a full size image from the attribute called `data-size` found in my a tag.

I'm looping through the a tags using `.each` and then finding the attribute data-size using `.attr`.

However, It saying that split is undefined? When I use console.log I can see the width and height like so `2340x1258`.

Why I can't I split this up into an array?

Please see below:

```
$('#project-gallery figure a').each(function (i, v) {    // build items array

        var size = console.log($(this).attr('data-size').split("x"));

        svi_items.push({
            src: $(v).attr('href'),
            w: $(v).size[0],
            h: $(v).size[1],
            msrc: $(v).data('imgthumb'),
            title: $(v).find('img').attr('title')
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
w: $(v).size[0],
h: $(v).size[1],
```

with:

```
w: size[0],
h: size[1],
```

and

```
var size = console.log($(this).attr('data-size').split("x"));
```

with:

```
var size = $(this).attr('data-size').split("x");
```